# How to use Kdevelop to write c++ programs ? 

Tags: programming, c++

How I can build c++ applications using Kdevelop. Where I can find tutorials for kDevelop4 ?
How to set the path for it ?

How I can  build a GUI application using Kdevelop 4.2?

Whenever I try to run any program it says " Process error : could not start the program, make sure the path is specified corectly"

what path I need to set ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the manual in order to learn how to set up [launches](http://userbase.kde.org/KDevelop4/Manual/Running_programs)

Comment: Thank you Michael but i have seen that before. Your reply is not satisfactory. That giude is too small and does not covers most of the things. I can run c++ code. The problem is with the QT and GUI  Rails applications. I want some tutorial on how to build rails and qt based gui applications. Here is a more complete tutorial which I have found but this one is for kdevelop3.X not for kdev4. http://www.beginning-kdevelop-programming.co.uk/

Comment: The screen-shots on KDE and on Ubuntu are much different. I dont even find the GUI builder shown on that tutorial.

Comment: In your question you never mentioned anything about Qt and GUI Rails applications. If you expect me to do mind-reading, I think that's a bit much to ask for...

Comment: Sorry friend. I forgot to mention it. Now Im using Code Blocks and very happy with it. I dont want to use Kdev4 any more.